# Involution on $2\times 2$ matrices

Tags: matrices, cubics, invariant-theory, schur-complement, roots-of-cubics

Show that the map on $2\times 2$ matrices

\begin{eqnarray} 
\left( \begin{matrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{matrix} \right)\overset{\Phi}{\mapsto} \left( \begin{matrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{matrix} \right)\cdot \left( \begin{matrix} 2 (a c - b^2) & a d - b c\\ a d - b c & 2(b d - c^2) \end{matrix} \right)^{-1} \cdot \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)
\end{eqnarray}

is an involution, that is $\Phi\circ \Phi=\operatorname{Id}$

Notes:

1. For convenience, one could treat $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ as independent variables, with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.
2. If we consider the form $F(x,y) =a x^3 + 3 b x^2 y + 3 c x y^2 + d$, then the [Hessian determinant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hessian.html) is a quadratic form with matrix coefficients (up to a constant( $\left( \begin{matrix} 2 (a c - b^2) & a d - b c\\ a d - b c & 2(b d - c^2) \end{matrix} \right)$. Its determinant is up to a constant the discriminant of the cubic form $F$. See also the matrix
   $\left(\begin{matrix} a& b &c \\
   b&c&d\end{matrix}\right)$ and its $2\times 2$ minors.
3. If instead of the inverse on the second factor we consider the adjugate, then we don't have to worry about denominators. Then the composition will be a constant times the matrix.
4. One could consider an alternate map with the third factor on RHS given by $\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$ . This is connected to the covariant $t$ for cubics, and  an [involution on triplets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4685990/involution-on-triplets) ( the roots of the cubic).  Note that the square of the map is in this case $-\operatorname{Id}$.
5. One can show that we have an involution by direct calculation ( RHS could be multiplied by an arbitrary fixed constant).
   It would be nice to have a proof involving some shortcuts. Maybe everything is just something basic.

Any feedback would be appreciated!